# How to switch mouse pointer shape or size when crossing monitors?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse, mouse-cursor

I have dual/triple monitor, and I need different mouse pointer size on each monitor.

I'm looking for a way to change mouse cursort depending on the monitor where the mouse cursor is at.

Can it be done with windows settings?
Is there a mouse event / trigger that can activate a script when the mouse crosses certain border?
Or any other way that is light on resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can it be done with windows settings?

No, Windows does not have such an option, except to scale the entire
monitor's resolution.

> Is there a mouse event / trigger that can activate a script when the mouse crosses certain border?

There isn't one, so you will need to write it yourself.

A good tool would be to use
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
The script to write will need to loop on a timer, checking on which
monitor is the cursor, and changing the pointer's size
(without changing the pointer itself).

Note that I can see some problems here with programs that requires another
cursor size, since this will override the current size.

> Or any other way that is light on resources?

Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it by adjustding different scale/layout for each display in the Display Settings, which makes (also) the mouse pointer larger on the relevant screen